# Group by the day of the month - Kotlin Logic Problem

Tags: kotlin

I'm stuck with the logic. So here it is, I have one model class Note:

```
data class Note(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val date: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

I have a list of multiple notes in my app `List<Note>`. And I need a way to convert that list into a Map. Where key will be the `date: Long`, and the value will be `List<Note>`. So: `Map<Long, List<Note>>` . I need to group those notes by the day of the month. For example, if multiple notes were created on October 31th, then they should be grouped in a single list of Notes, within a Map.

I'm really not sure how can I achieve that. Always had troubles with those date values. I will appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a helper property to get the date in LocalDate format, which would make it easy to sort by day. If you were using this a lot, repeatedly, you might consider adding it as a member property that isn't computed on each retrieval (but not in the constructor because it is computed from another property that participates in `equals` and `hashcode`).

```
val Note.localDate: LocalDate
    get() = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
```

Then you can use `groupBy` to create your Map of dates to lists.

```
val notesByLocalDate = notes.groupBy(Note::localDate) // or { it.localDate }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works!
Btw, I should add that extension property inside the body of a Note class, right?

Comment: No, if you add it as an extension inside the class, it will be difficult to use from outside the class (you would have to wrap it in a subject-as-receiver scope function like `with`, `run` or `apply` to be able to use it). Extension functions should usually be defined outside a class. Or you could define it inside the class, but not as an extension. It’s a style/encapsulation choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be one of the "*just because you can, doesn't mean you should*".

```
.groupBy {
    val noteCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    noteCalendar.timeInMillis = it.date
    val day = noteCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val month = noteCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val year = noteCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val dayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    dayCalendar.timeInMillis = 0L
    dayCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
    dayCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    dayCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    dayCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)

    dayCalendar.timeInMillis
}
```

Trying to group something by its date of creation in milliseconds will result in no grouping because nothing is created at the exact same time*. So the only way for you to group it is to translate the date range of which those things happen into one value. In this case noon of that day to avoid timezone problems.

...but again I would recommend not grouping this by `Long`.